# javascript: Unexpected Evaluation Behavior with Ternary Operator

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator, operator-precedence

**Problem:** The function is not returning the value that is expected (3).

The following code does not evaluate as expected returning 1.  I've found that this is due to the usage of the ternary operator.  What about the ternary causes the return value to be unexpected? Is it precedence? The ternary operator is right associative according to the mdn specifications.

```
function foo()
{
    var x = 1;
    var flag = true;

    function bar(a,b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    var y = bar(2,2) - (flag) ? x : 0;

    return y;   
}    
alert(foo());
```

Note that if I modify the line:

```
var y = bar(2,2) - (flag) ? x : 0;
```

to

```
var y = bar(2,2) - ((flag) ? x : 0);
```

The above code will act as expected returning 3.

Also note that if I replace the function with any type of float

```
var y = 3 - (flag) ? x : 0;
```

The same unexpected return value is evaluated to 1.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You guessed correctly: It is precendence. The operator `-` is evaluated before the ternary operator.

```
var y = bar(2,2) - (flag) ? x : 0;
```

is evaluated as

```
var y = (bar(2,2) - (flag)) ? x : 0;
```

You can see the operator precedence here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Note that the "conditional" (ternary) operator is way down on the list.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is that you're assuming space or parenthesis delimit automatically.

```
var y= bar(2,2) - (flag) ? x : 0;
```

is the same as

```
var y= (bar(2,2) - (flag)) ? x : 0;
```

and is not the same as

```
var y= bar(2,2) - ((flag) ? x : 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because when you leave the code like this:

```
var y = bar(2,2) - (flag) ? x : 0;
```

It evaluates to this:

```
var y = (bar(2,2) - (flag)) ? x : 0;
```